# Персонаж не двигается в 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCntrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        rb.MovePosition (rb.positon + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Вылазит ошибка:

All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!
UnityEditor.SceneView:ShowCompileErrorNotification()

И ещё одна ошибка:

Assets\Scripts\PlayerCntrl.cs(17,29): error CS1061: 'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'positon' and no accessible extension method 'positon' accepting a first argument of type 'Rigidbody2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Это не весь текст ошибки

Comment: Весь, просто поверь

Comment: Не верю, что это весь текст ошибки, но как минимум что такое `rb.positon`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы слегка неверно получаете доступ к позиции. Вот так работает. И я бы советовал делать всё, что связано с физикой в FixedUpdate.

```
using UnityEngine;
    
    public class PlayerCntrl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed = 20f;
        private Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    
        void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
    
        void Update()//Здесь лучше void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + Vector3.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Все запускается, но мой персонаж двигается только при прыжке
Что делать?

Comment: Либо у Вас ещё какой то скрипт на персонаже висит, который не дает ему двигаться, если он на коллайдере стоит, либо в настройках параметров самого объекта сцены какие-нибудь неверные значения стоят

Comment: Он двигается только отрывками, если долго задерживать кнопку

Comment: Ну так я же Вам выше написал, используйте:

FixedUpdate()